# How to create Azure AD B2C Identity Experience Framework policy key where name & secret are input params using powershell command

Tags: azure-devops, active-directory, azure-active-directory, powershell-5.0, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

How to create Azure AD B2C Identity Experience Framework policy key where name & secret are input params using powershell command. I am not finding any source on internet for it

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't seem to be a **direct** method to add policy key using powershell. All methods [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/?view=azureadps-2.0-preview#trust-framework-policy-management).

You could use [Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/trustframeworkkeyset-generatekey?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) with Powershell as a workaround. There is an [article](https://thesleepyadmins.com/2020/10/24/connecting-to-microsoft-graphapi-using-powershell/) about connecting to Microsoft GraphAPI Using PowerShell.

**Note:** Add application permission `TrustFrameworkKeySet.ReadWrite.All` first, and grant consent for your tenant.

```
$Uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/trustFramework/keySets/{id}/generateKey"
    
$Body = @{
      use="sig"
      kty="RSA"
      nbf="1508969811"
      exp="1508969811"
    }

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Uri -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $($token)"} -Method Post -ContentType "application/json" -Body $Body
```

---

**UPDATE:**

The name of policy key is `id` of the [trustframeworkKeySet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/trustframeworkkeyset?view=graph-rest-beta#properties).

Key type is `kty` of [trustFrameworkKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/trustframeworkkey?view=graph-rest-beta#properties). And secret is related to `oct`.

So, you need to create keySet first, then generate the key.

[Create keySet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/trustframework-post-keysets?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http):

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/trustFramework/keySets
Content-type: application/json

{
  "id": "keyset1 like B2C_1A_test"  
}
```

Comment: How can i enter secret and the name of the policy key as parameter s

Comment: I explain them in my UPDATE. If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer, thank you.